# how to visit kmm expect class's methods with generic type in java code

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I define expect class named 'Common.kt' in common module like this：

```
expect open class Common<T>() {

    fun play()

    fun pause()

    fun get(): T?

}
```

and create a empty actual class in androidMain, then declared it as field in 'CommonData.kt' like follow :

```
class CommonData {

    val value = Common<Int>()

}
```

then，new 'CommonData' object in app module，I can visit 'CommonData.value.play()' in Kotlin file，but I can't visit 'CommonData.value.play()' in Java file

```
public class Test {

    public void get(){
        CommonData data = new CommonData();
        // Cannot resolve method 'play()'
        data.getValue().play();
    }

}
```

and error message is:

```
 "Cannot resolve method 'play()' "
```

I think it might has connections with expect，because it's ok when I remove 'expect' declaration，everything runs well。

So, is there are any compiler options in build.gradle can help me to visit expect class' method in java code？

Android Studio：Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1

Kotlin：1.8.0

Kotlin MultiPlatform Mobile：1.8.10

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin Multiplatform projects, the `expect` keyword is employed to define platform-specific declarations, and `actual` is used to furnish platform-specific implementations for those declarations. The `expect` and `actual` declarations enable you to write platform-independent code in the common module and supply platform-specific implementations in the respective platform modules (e.g., Android, iOS).

However, when it comes to utilizing `expect` classes in Java code, you will encounter some limitations. Java does not have inherent support for Kotlin's `expect` and `actual` declarations. Consequently, you won't be able to directly access the methods of the `expect` class in Java code.

To work around this restriction, you can create an `actual` implementation for your `expect` class in the Android module and then expose a Java-friendly API from there.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Create an `actual` implementation for the `Common` class in the Android module:

In the Android module (app module in your case), generate a new Kotlin file, let's say `CommonAndroid.kt`, and provide the `actual` implementation for the `Common` class:

```kotlin
actual open class Common<T> actual constructor() {

    actual fun play() {
        // Android-specific implementation here
    }

    actual fun pause() {
        // Android-specific implementation here
    }

    actual fun obtain(): T? {
        // Android-specific implementation here
        return null
    }
}
```

2. Modify `Common.kt` in the common module:

In the common module, make sure to remove the `expect` modifier from the `Common` class, as you will provide the implementation in the Android module:

```kotlin
open class Common<T>() {

    fun play() {
        // Common implementation here (can be empty)
    }

    fun pause() {
        // Common implementation here (can be empty)
    }

    fun obtain(): T? {
        // Common implementation here (can be empty)
        return null
    }
}
```

3. Use the `Common` class in the Android module:

Now, you can use the `Common` class in your Android-specific Kotlin files:

```kotlin
class CommonData {

    val value = Common<Int>()

    fun someFunction() {
        value.play()
    }
}
```

4. Access the `Common` class from Java code:

To access the `Common` class and its methods from Java code, you can create a wrapper or a Java-friendly API in the Android module:

```java
// Java wrapper for Common class
public class CommonWrapper<T> {
    private final Common<T> common;

    public CommonWrapper() {
        common = new Common<>();
    }

    public void play() {
        common.play();
    }

    public void pause() {
        common.pause();
    }

    public T obtain() {
        return common.obtain();
    }
}

// Usage in Java
CommonWrapper<Integer> commonWrapper = new CommonWrapper<>();
commonWrapper.play();
```

Comment: thanks for answering，i had defined a actual class for Common in androidMain，and our app needs CommonData in common module，but some old modules written by java，so we also wanna to provide CommonData for these old modules。if there needs define a wrapper class, it's seems not good for compatibility of old modules。